# Reducing the length of a long for/if statement

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm currently trying to make the code of an app I'm developing a bit more efficient and easier to read. Basically what this does is retrieve an array from NSUserDefaults of player names, and fills in the 6 text boxes (tagged 6-11) with these names. If there isn't an existing array it'll use another set of names. Any ideas for simplifying this code would be appreciated.

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameArray"]];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [playerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
                if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                    UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)view;
                    if (txtField.tag == 6) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:0]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Peter";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 7) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:1]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Julia";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 8) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:2]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Durgan";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 9) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:3]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Bob";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 10) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:4]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Iseland";
                        }
                    }
                    if (txtField.tag == 11) {
                        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"]) {
                            txtField.text = [names objectAtIndex:5]; }
                        else {
                            txtField.text = @"Player";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        [self saveNames];
    }
```

Comment: This question might be better asked on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, I have posted it on there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your could do this:

```
NSArray *defaultNames = @[@"Peter", @"Julia",...];
int offsetIndex = 6;
BOOl needCustomNames = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"customNames"];
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) 
    {
        UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)view;
        int index = [txtField tag]-offsetIndex;
        if (tag >= 6 && tag <= 11)
        {
            if (needCustomNames)
                textField.text = [names objectAtIndex:index];
            else
                textField.text = [defaultNames objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
}
```

For example, you called too many times the same lines in the `for` loop, like checking if you need to use or not a custom names (`NSUserDefaults` line).
I use an `NSArray` for the custom names to mimic the same logic, and used an offset to clarify it.

Comment: Nice answer. But if your tag value will be random (like 2, 23, 65) then you may face problem. For a general case you can use Switch statement. It'll be simple and fast. "switch statement" will execute the right case only, not all like "if statement".    @Dale Townsend

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to analyse your Code for redundance and exclude them in separate methods. so you have to call only the extern method than every code-party again and again.